# VueJS Accordion Table - Appears outside of the table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table where the data is fetched using ajax. I'm trying to have a table where each row has an associated hidden row and clicking on the row toggles the display of the hidden row. The hidden row contains an accordion.

The problem is that the accordion is getting all messed up and shows at the bottom of the table, rather than showing below the particular row that it was clicked on.

My code is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns">
           <span v-if="column == 'Predictive Price'">
                {{column}} 
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle" v-tooltip="msg"></i>
           </span>
           <span v-else-if="column == 'Actual Price'">
                 {{column}}
           <i class="fa fa-info-circle" v-tooltip="tooltip.actual_price"></i>
                              </span>
                              <span v-else>

                                {{column}}
                              </span>
                          </th>
                          <th>Actions</th>
                       </tr>

                   </thead>

                   <tbody>
                      <tr v-for="row in model" @click="showRow">

                          <td>
                              {{row.id}}
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              {{row.company_customer.customer_name}}
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                              <small>
                                {{row.pickup_addr.address_1}}, {{row.pickup_addr.city}}, {{row.pickup_addr.postcode}}
                              </small>
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                              <small>
                                  {{row.pickup_addr.address_1}}, {{row.pickup_addr.city}}, {{row.pickup_addr.postcode}}
                              </small>
                          </td>

                          <td>
                                &pound;{{row.predictive_price}}
                          </td>

                          <td>
                                &pound;{{row.actual_price}}
                          </td>

                          <td>
                              n/a
                          </td>

                          <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" v-if="contentVisible">
                                  <div class="accordian-body">
                                      ACCORDION 
                                  </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                      </tr>



                  </tbody>
              </table>


<script>

export default {

    methods: {
        data() {
          return {
            msg: 'This is just an estimation!',

            tooltip: {
                actual_price: 'Click on the price to edit it.'
            },

            contentVisible: false,

          }
      },
      rowRow() {
          this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible;
      }
    }

}

</script>
```

Where can I place the accordion div in order for it to display correctly?

EDIT:

Please see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/355/

Comment: You put your accordion `tr` inside the other `tr`. Put it after. A `tr` cannot be the child of another `tr`.

Comment: @RoyJ Please see this fiddle: As you can see, it's not performing to what I need it to do: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/355/ even putting it outside of the `tr`

Comment: Is the accordion supposed to be a row or is it in a cell? Or rather, it looks like you want an accordion for each row?

Comment: @BertEvans I want the accordion on the line below. So, it would essentially expand below the particular row but should not expand ALL of the rows. Sadly, at the moment the JSFiddle expands all of the rows and also appears on the side rather than an extra row (if you like)

Comment: @BertEvans This works perfectly! Thank you very much. In terms of performance, is it better to load the data for the accordion on `page load` or have the data loaded/shown through ajax on click?

Comment: @Phorce I moved the fiddle into an answer. As far as performance, it's hard to say. What performance are you optimizing for? How much data will be in the accordion? The accordion won't even be rendered until they say, so I expect most performance issues would be relatively negligible (depending on how much data of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want an accordion associated with every row, so really, you want *two* rows for each item of your data.

You can accomplish that by moving your `v-for` to a `template` tag that wraps both of your rows.

Additionally, you need to control whether content is visible on a row by row basis, so add a `contentVisible` property to each data item and use it to control whether your second row is visible or not.

```js
console.clear()

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    testing: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Customer 1",
        contentVisible: false

      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Customer 1",
        contentVisible: false

      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Customer 3",
        contentVisible: false

      },
    ],
    columns: ["id", "name"]
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.testing);
  },

  methods: {
    showRow(data) {
      this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible;

    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns">
          {{column}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <template v-for="row in testing">
        <tr @click="row.contentVisible = !row.contentVisible">
           <td>{{row.id}}</td>
           <td>{{row.name}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr v-if="row.contentVisible">
           <td :colspan="columns.length" >
             <div class="accordian-body">
               afasfafs
             </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/357/).

Comment: I've just realised something.. I get your implementation `row.contentVisible = !row.contentVisible` however, in my instance (the jsfiddle was just an example) I am using `store` which returns an object of data from a `axios` request.. I don't have `row.contentVisible` within this data.. Is it possible to therefore add a row to each of the data or simply handle this another way?

Comment: @phorce just use `map` in your `axios` response handler to add the property to the data.

Comment: Although would be a solution, this application is real-time.. So by adding a map to the store wouldn't work as everytime something is updated then it would close the accordion aha!

Comment: @phorce would you like to ask a separate question that handles these additional constraints?

Comment: I just have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551563/vuejs-accordion-table-constraints-for-real-time-based-system Any help would be greatly appreciated :)