# VueJS Accordion Table -- Constraints for real time based system

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue-component

This question follows on from posted here:

[VueJS Accordion Table - Appears outside of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544994/vuejs-accordion-table-appears-outside-of-the-table)

The answer provided by @Bert Evans is good, however, in the system that I'm developing, there are some constraints which is not making it work.

The main constraint is the fact that I'm developing a real-time based system, which takes advantage of the `store` so when something is edited by a user, then the an action is triggered which pulls all the data again from an ajax call. The solution provided uses `contentVisible` and although I can map this when the action is called, **the main problem is that whenever the action is called, the `contentVisible` is being set to `false` by default causing the accordion to close.**

I have tried to create a copy of the data, however, this is not sufficient enough. Basically, I need a way to detect that someone has clicked on a particular row and then show the accordion below it.

Any suggestions?

```js
console.clear()

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    testing: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Customer 1",
        contentVisible: false

      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Customer 1",
        contentVisible: false

      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Customer 3",
        contentVisible: false

      },
    ],
    columns: ["id", "name"]
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.testing);
  },

  methods: {
    showRow(data) {
      this.contentVisible = !this.contentVisible;

    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns">
          {{column}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <template v-for="row in testing">
        <tr @click="row.contentVisible = !row.contentVisible">
           <td>{{row.id}}</td>
           <td>{{row.name}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr v-if="row.contentVisible">
           <td :colspan="columns.length" >
             <div class="accordian-body">
               afasfafs
             </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If all the data is replaced, how do you know which ones should be open?

Comment: @Roy J - Thanks for the reply. Ideally, don't really need to know which ones are open when the data is replaced. Just the accordion needs to know which row is open. I.e. if the data is replaced then it should not really update the accordion state as a row (100) could have the accordion expanded but row (1) is changed.. Therefore row 1 shouldn't be effected. If this makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

I'll offer a slightly simplified version of Bert Evans' answer (since deleted), in which expanded state is tracked separately from the data. I just used a dictionary instead of an array to track the `id`s of which ones are open, because it's easier to check for membership and delete.

```js
console.clear()

const testing = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Customer 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Customer 2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Customer 3",
  },
]

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    testing,
    expanded: {},
    columns: ["id", "name"],
    replacedCounter: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.testing = testing
      this.replacedCounter++
    }, 3000)
  },
  methods: {
    expand(id) {
      if (id in this.expanded)
        this.$delete(this.expanded, id);
      else
        this.$set(this.expanded, id, true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns">
          {{column}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <template v-for="row in combined">
        <tr @click="expand(row.id)">
           <td>{{row.id}}</td>
           <td>{{row.name}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr v-if="row.id in expanded">
           <td :colspan="columns.length" >
             <div class="accordian-body">
               afasfafs
             </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Testing: {{testing}} <br /> Expanded: {{expanded}} <br /> Replaced: {{replacedCounter}}
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to work it into your answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: With your idea the computed isn't even necessary anymore. I think it's much better.

Comment: With this approach you can just use `v-if="row.id in expanded"` and eliminate the computed.

Comment: @RoyJ Is it possible to allow for only one accordion to be open at once? Can I just have an if statement that if the count is > 1 delete all of the remain ones apart from the one you've just clicked on?

Comment: Make expanded a scalar containing the currently-open id. The test for open is then `v-if="row.id === expanded"`